# Fonts and 'analog' clock in Emily Riehl's 2020 ACT conference slides

Tags: beamer, fonts

I was recently looking at [these](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/matrices.pdf) slides made by Emily Riehl for the [2020 edition](https://act2020.mit.edu/) of the [Applied Category Theory](https://www.appliedcategorytheory.org/) conference.

Here's a screenshot of one of the slides:

[image]

Is this a known template? And if so, where can I find it?

Otherwise, does anyone know which font is this? I've tried looking online via some 'pdf font readers' with no luck. I am also interested in the 'clock' displayed in the top right; it changes as the slides advance. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Similar to clock, someone asked for progress bar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567258/

Comment: I do something similar in ConTeXt for [my slides](http://cim.mcgill.ca/~adityam/talks/20-umich.pdf) using the [visualcounter](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter) module (which I wrote). This is for ConTeXt and uses Metapost for drawing. The main advantage is that it can easily hook into any counter (and not just page number). See the [manual](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter/blob/master/visualcounter.pdf) for more examples of counters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume David answered your font related questions? The "analog clock" really is just a pie chart. Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf-pie}

\newcommand\pieofprogress  {%
                        \begin{tikzpicture}
                            \tikzset{lines/.style={draw=none}}
                            \pie[   rotate=90, 
                                    hide number, 
                                    sum=auto, 
                                    radius=.25,
                                    color={lime,cyan},
                                    style={lines}
                                ]   {
                                        \inserttotalframenumber-
                                        \insertframenumber/,
                                        \insertframenumber/
                                    }
                        \end{tikzpicture}
                    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Frame \#1}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.85\textwidth}
            \centering  This is number one, 
                        and the fun hast just begun … 
            \column{0.15\textwidth}
            \pieofprogress
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Frame \#2}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.85\textwidth}
            \centering  This is number two, 
                        and I'm taking off her shoe …
            \column{0.15\textwidth}
            \pieofprogress
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Frame \#3}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.85\textwidth}
            \centering  This is number three,
                        and my hand is on her knee …
            \column{0.15\textwidth}
            \pieofprogress
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}    

    \begin{frame}{Frame \#4}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.85\textwidth}
            \centering  This is number four,
                        and she’s asking me for more …
            \column{0.15\textwidth}
            \pieofprogress
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

You'll probably want to stick it in your header or footer theme or some other appropriate template, but the principle should be clear.

Comment: Great; I am not on my PC right now but  I will try this and report back (or accept the answer if everything works). Thanks!

Comment: This is great; one last question, do you know how to avoid the having the black lines? E.g. if I set the colors to red and blue, the two slices of the pie are delimited by black lines. I can set ```lines/.style={draw=white, thin}``` and it kind of does trick, but how could I make the lines vanish altogether?

Comment: Sure. Just use `draw=none`. I have revised my answer above.

Comment: One more thing: I have only now taken a look at the original slide deck and noticed that her pie chart progresses counter-clockwise. I find that less intuitive, so my example does not :)

Comment: awesome, many thanks for taking the time to answer :)  I will award the bounty as soon as its available. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

it's made with lualatex and beamer using these fonts (not all of which are free):

```
$pdffonts matrices.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
RWJBVP+GillSans-Light                CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     18  0
ALDFDQ+LatinModernMath-Regular       CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     19  0
MOBCJY+LatinModernMath-Regular       CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     20  0
AIZVPP+MnSymbol10                    Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      33  0
AIZVPP+MnSymbol10                    Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      34  0
MYTKLN+LatinModernMath-Regular       CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     35  0
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Regarding the clock gadget, would you by any chance know how is it implemented? I've tried searching this site but haven't seen anything in this 'minimalistic' style.